# is android account sync with contacts also possible in blackberry?

Tags: android, blackberry, twitter, synchronization, account

I am very new in blackberry development and I am researching for an issue but could not find anything. In android, your application can be seen in accounts and you can sync your account with the contacts (for example twitter) Is such a thing possible in blackberry 4.6.1 and above? Any idea and source would be great.thanks.